# Range-based loop for linked list

Tags: c++14

I guess I am missing something in operator ++(). I want to implement Range based loop in following Linked list code. I am not sure what I am missing in it.

```
struct Node {
    Node() {}
    Node(int e, Node* n) : elem(e), next(n) {  }
    int elem = 0;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node& operator ++() {
        Node* current = this;
        if( current != nullptr ) {
            current = current->next;
            return *current;
        }
    }

    int& operator *() {
        return this->elem;
    }

    bool operator !=(Node const& rhs) const {
        return this->elem != rhs.elem;
    }

    int* begin() {
        return &this->elem;
    }

    int* end() {
        return nullptr;
    }

};

void add(Node& n, int x) {
    n.next = new Node(x, n.next);
}


int main() {

    Node head;
    add(head, 1);
    add(head, 2);
    add(head, 3);
    add(head, 4);
    add(head, 5);

    for (int x : head) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "2nd " << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int& x : head) {
        x = 7;
    }

    std::cout << "3rd " << std::endl;
    for (const int& x : head) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what to add in ++ operator. I want it in same struct instead of having separate Iterator class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Node` structure contains a single `int` element. This `int` element is totally unrelated to any other nodes `int` element.

What you do with `begin` and the increment operator `++` is treat *one* nodes `int` element as the first element of an array. That means your code will immediately go out of bounds.

To solve your iteration problem I first suggest that you abstract out the list and the nodes into different structures. Then you can easily make a wrapper structure which contains a pointer to the current node in the list iteration. This wrapper structure then need to overload the `++` operator which will the go to the next node in the list.

---

Somewhat graphically it could be something like

```
+------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
| list | --> | node 1 | --> | node 2 | --> | node 3 | --> ...
+------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
             ^
             |
             +----------+
             | iterator |
             +----------+
```

Then you increment the iterator you get this:

```
+------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
| list | --> | node 1 | --> | node 2 | --> | node 3 | --> ...
+------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
                            ^
                            |
                            +----------+
                            | iterator |
                            +----------+
```

And so on...